# Possible to have multiple SAME WCF window service on same machine

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Kind of like the named instanced sql server.

I'd like to install the same wcf window service on the same machine so having multiple instances of it.

I'd like each of them to connect to a different Databases (different environment)

Answer (score 1):

Just configure each one for different endpoint addresses in the config file, should work like a charm.

Comment: I'd like each of them to connect to a different Databases (different environment).

Comment: Of course, you also have to be able to install more than one instance of the Windows Service itself.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something fancy, using a custom ServiceHostFactory. It could create one ServiceHost per environment you wanted. Each custom ServiceHost would then create instances of your service to operate in that particular environment.